# Swing, AWT-EventQueue locked

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jconsole, jide

In my swing application the whole application is hanging when invoking click at one of the nodes (only one).
I used jconsole to investigate the problem a little bit more and what I see when invoking this "hanging event" in `AWT-EventQueue-1` occurs

```
locked java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock@49f8e092
```

What can cause such behaviour? is it the reason why application doesn't response?

Comment: Please consider posting the relevant section of your code or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) version highlighting your issue

Comment: it is hard here for example - because it is a production code, and more doesn't work only at specific environment (probably because of number of records in db) I wanted only a little help with interpreting this "locked java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock@49f8e092
" or maybe someone had a problems with jide and a similar error. if not ok.

Comment: Have you tried googling "locked java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock" ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: ermmm, I vote for an SSCCE as well :D

Comment: For an SSCCE, here is one: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue101.html but I don't know if the OP can relate to that problem trivially. Anyway, the problem seems to be coming from manipulation of AWT/Swing UI elements within another thread than the EDT. The solution is always the same, move all those method calls in the EDT with SwingUtilities.invokeLater or SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait